# Is it possible to stop item sorting and get the XY co-ordinate of a child within cdkDropList?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk, angular-material-7

While adding an Item within cdkDropList it comes to available left most position because of the data sorting property, but I would like to stop the auto arrange feature in my cdkDropList. Is it feasible? If yes then how?

Also is it possible to get the XY co-ordinate of those child items? need some help.

```
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="items" cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="item" *ngFor="let item of items;">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing anything in response to the drop event? You are supposed to move items around in the backing array yourself.

Example adapted from [the official docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview):

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.items, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
}
```

You also have to import `moveItemInArray` from `@angular/cdk/drag-drop`.

Comment: Yes I have used the function to move the item index, but I am concern about the position of items. 
For example, I have a drop list with 500px and each of my item width is 100px. That means I have space for five items in the cdkDropList. Now I want to add two items in 2nd and 4th position of the list, rest places will be blank. Is it possible?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, all you need are items with empty names in your backing array, so `items` will contain `[blank, item1, blank, item2, blank]` (`blank` being the item with empty name).

Comment: Gabriel Negut Yes, you are partially correct. Only the `blank` means a blank space, no item with empty name because I can add new items at those space later or can drag existing two items at those positions.

Comment: You can always use some custom logic (instead of `moveItemInArray`) to replace blanks with "real" items instead of swapping their positions, depending of what exactly is your desired behaviour.